# How to create an object using local variables in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, scope

I'm hoping someone can help me understand a thing or two.  I'm trying to create an array of objects from information that is submitted via a form on a page.  My variables in my createItem() are local, which are used to populate the object constructor for new items. In turn this new item is suppose to push to an Array, but once the function ends the item doesn't stay in the Array.

Here's the code:

```
var itemList = [];
var newItem;

// item constructor function
function item(name, quantity, length, width, height, cubicFeet, totalCubicFeet) {
  this.name = name;
  this.quantity = quantity;
  this.length = length;
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
  this.cubicFeet = cubicFeet;
  this.totalCubicFeet = totalCubicFeet;
}

//Getters
function getItemName() {
  var name = document.getElementById("item-name").value;
  return name;
}

function getWidth() {
  var width = parseInt(document.getElementById("width").value);
  return width;
}

function getHeight() {
  var height = parseInt(document.getElementById("height").value);
  return height;
}

function getLength() {
  var length = parseInt(document.getElementById("length").value);
  return length;
}

function getQuantity() {
  var quantity = parseInt(document.getElementById("quantity").value);
  return quantity;
}


//calculates cubic footage of item from inches
function getCubicFeet(length, width, height) {
  var cubicFeet = Math.ceil((length / 12) * (width /12) * (height / 12));
  return cubicFeet;
}

//prints list of items to console
function printList() {

  for (var i = 0; i <= itemList.length; i++) {
      console.log(itemList[i]);
  }

}

//retrieves the information from the form and creates an object OnClick
function createItem() {

  var name = getItemName();
  var quantity = getQuantity();
  var length = getLength();
  var width = getWidth();
  var height = getHeight();
  var cubicFeet = getCubicFeet(length, width, height);
  var totalCubicFeet = cubicFeet * quantity;

  newItem =  new item(name, quantity, length, width, height, cubicFeet, totalCubicFeet);

  itemList.push(newItem);

  printList();

}
```

Do I need to create global variables for each of the item values in order to make them stick and then push that to the array?  Or is there a way to acheive this using local var as I have here?

Comment: Please make a full fiddle with the form.

Comment: I have tested this. The itemList contains the value even after the function is over.